# Combine mongo document arrays to one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For my document as below, is this possible with aggregation to combine those two records array into one array, similar to flatmap in java?

```
{ _id: 123,`
 values:[1,2,3,5]
}

{_id:234,
values:[7,98,33,1]
}
```

I want the output as

{ values: [1,2,3,5,7,98,33,1]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array first to get single elements, then use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to combine all elements

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$values"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      values: { $push: "$values" }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `$group` stage with some data restructuring will do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            values: {$push: "$values"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            values: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$values",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```